# capitalization of mathematics

Tags: capitalization

I have to write a CV in english for an application for a Master's degree programme. I want to write "Emphasis: pure Mathematics". How shall I write "pure Mathematics"? Like this, or "Pure Mathematics"?

How do I write Mathematics in a running text? Always with capital M? And am I enrolled in the Bachelor's programme mathematics oder Mathematics? Is it B.Sc. Mathematics or B.Sc. mathematics?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd only write "Mathematics" with a capital when it's part of a title of a program, or a degree, e.g.

> B.Sc. Mathematics.

You do not capitalise common nouns such as "mathematics" in all normal circumstances. You (more or less) always write "mathematics" in the running text with a lower-case "m". You would have,

> Emphasis: pure mathematics

So you would have something like:

> Degree: BSc Mathematics

But:

> I achieved a Bachelor of Science degree in mathematics, with an emphasis on pure mathematics.

Comment: Thanks. And do I write "Complementary subject: informatics" or with a capital I? $Student tutor for mathematics, physics and french" oder capital T,M,P,F? What about emphasis in school? Emphasis: Mathematics or mathematics? Thanks so far :)

Comment: @R.A. I would definitely write "informatics" as you have it, because this is the name of a subject here, a common noun, not the title of a program. You might do a course entitled "Introductory Informatics Part 2", but this would be an introductory informatics course (here this is not a title of a course). There is a possible exception, though, which is that some people like to capitalise the first element after a colon. So "Complementary subjects: Informatics, physics, chemistry" would be ok. You would have "mathematics, physics and French". French, the name of a language, is a proper noun.

Comment: That helps :) And do you write "Student tutor for mathematics" or Tutor? An it is "Bachelor's degree programme Mathematics" since it is a title for a degree programme?

Comment: @R.A. You could sort of do either, I suppose. Your job title might be given as "Student Tutor" or even "Student Tutor of Mathematics" (because this is part of a title), I guess, on a form perhaps. But you would generally say something like "I worked as a student tutor of mathematics for 2 years" and, in all cases, English doesn't capitalise all that much. You're slightly making me doubt myself now, maybe other people will think differently, maybe there are style guides that advise differently, but in general, I studied maths and physics and I had maths teachers and physics teachers